# Equation for binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Let $n\in\Bbb N$, $k\in\{0,\dots,2n\}$. Is this equation valid? $$\binom{2n}{k}=\sum_{i=0,\dots,n\\ j=0,\dots,n\\i+j=k}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it holds. We have that
$$\sum_{i=0,\dots,n\\ j=0,\dots,n\\i+j=k}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=\sum_{i=0,\dots,n\\ j=0,\dots,n\\i+j=k}[x^i](1+x)^{n}\cdot [x^j](1+x)^{n}=[x^k](1+x)^{2n}=\binom{2n}{k}.$$

Comment: Many thanks for such a beautiful explanation.